# Show Pending Transactions when I use metamask or any other platform

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask

When I try to sendTransaction using mainnet then it always show a pending status. How can I solve this?
I am using web3js and nodejs to send a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your transaction is underpriced and it wasn't added in any block yet. This is why it is stuck in `pending` mode.

At this moment the network is "clogged".

There is a website where you can check the recommended transaction gas pricing.

https://ethgasstation.info/